# How to determine which irrep the Hilbert space of states carry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

Is the following statement ([1]) correct?

[1] *If the universe has a symmetry under a group $G$, does this mean the Hilbert space carries a unitary representation formed by taking the direct product of all the irreps of the group $G$?.*

When considering symmetries in a non-relativistic theory, often we look for operators $\hat{S}$ such that the statement $$\Big[\hat{H},\hat{S}\Big]=0$$ is true for a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$. My confusion is that this Hamiltonian is usually formulated to only describe a certain type of particle e.g. the Pauli Hamiltonian for spin $\frac{1}{2}$, so the overarching general symmetry principles are lost.

Should there exist one-particle Hamiltonians $$\hat{H}_0, \;\hat{H}_\frac{1}{2},\;\hat{H}_1,\dots\;$$

where the $n$ in $\hat{H}_n$ refers to the spin of the particle? Also, I'm assuming that the list goes on indefinitely leading me to think that statement [1] is correct. Does this have something to do with all unitary representations on $\mathcal{H}$ are infinitely dimensional for $SO(1,3)$? i.e. Is there a proof that all the unitary representations on $\mathcal{H}$ of $SO(1,3)$ can be decomposed and written as a direct sum of all the irreps.

Another example is that non-relativistically, there exists an $SO(3)$ symmetry that leads to angular momentum. The state-space seems to carry a representation of the direct product of all the irreps of this group. Could someone confirm if what I've said is true or detail where I've gone wrong?

An example for which the above seems not to be true is when talking about internal symmetries however I'm not quite sure why. Is this because the theory is set up for the state space to carry a very *specific* unitary representation of the internal symmetry group?

Comment: What $SU(2)$ symmetry is the first paragraph referring to?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Non-relativistic spin

Comment: Surely I can if the Hamiltonian has a $2$ dimensional state space and only admits one-particle states.

Comment: edited to add to my answer

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks for your answer. How do I know which irreps a Hilbert space carries?

Comment: @DIRAC1930 if you don’t have a basis for your Hilbert space, or some information about the representation itself (in the form of characters or explicit matrix representation), you can’t know.  From the basis states you can construct the rep. and reduce it (if reducible) using the tool of representation theory; if you already have the characters, you can again use the standard tools.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero So if I understand correctly, it seems arbitrary how many irreps the state space will carry if a Lie group symmetry is found. Once that group is found or postulated, a specific Hamiltonian that is symmetric under a representation of that group is theorized. Then all the Hamiltonians that are symmetric under the other  irreps are found and it is then determined whether they are relevant and if they fit experimental data or not.

Comment: Surely in most cases it would be the other way around: you would start from a Hamiltonian (or a Lagrangian), find the symmetry group, and then organize states (single-particle or many-particle) in representations so as to block-diagonalize your Hamiltonian.

Comment: Of course if you are good at this it’s possible to reverse-engineering a Hamiltonian (or Lagrangian) that would have a specific symmetry group because general analysis of the representation theory of this putative group would lead to some contraints that would explain data.  In this sense finding a symmetry group that will work is educated guesswork and a bit of trial and error.

Comment: No.  A Hilbert need not carry *all* irreps of a group.  An example is Hilbert space for a spin-1/2 particle, which carries a single representation of SU(2).  The same holds for any group.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero But in principle, should there exist a Hilbert space for all the irreps. I.e. there exists a spin $1$ Hamiltonian etc. that describes something in the universe. Isn't this the Totalitarian Principle?

Comment: see Peter-Weyl theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What does the notation $L^2(G)$ mean in reference to QM?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, I deleted that part of my question.

Comment: It's very rude to change your question significantly after there's already been an answer, because now the answer doesn't make any sense. You should ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: @knzhou Why is it rude? Those answers helped me reformulate the question as it cleared up some of my misunderstandings. It's the same question just formulated differently. My previous questions got deleted as duplicates with the suggestion to edit instead of opening up another question.

Answer (score 5):

The actual irrep is not linked to the number of particles.  It is true that you can construct any irrep (of a semi-simple Lie group or algebra) by taking suitable tensor products of basic representations but this does not imply that these basic representations are “single particle representations”, while others are “multi-particle”.

For instance spherical harmonics of angular momentum $\ell$ span a vector space that carries a $2\ell+1$-dimensional irrep, irrespective of the number of particles involved.

Moreover, the tensor product of two $\ell=1$ irreps decomposes into $L=2,1,0$ so the singlet can hardly be thought as a 0-particle irrep, and the (antisymmetric) $L=1$ piece is a 2-particle irrep, despite being isomorphic to the original 1-particle $\ell=1$ pieces.

Summarizing (and repeating): there is no link between the representation labels and the number of particles.  The same applies to $SU(2)$.

If a Hilbert space carries a representation of a group, you cannot say anything about this irrep in general as it could be *any* irrep.

The Hilbert space does not have to carry *every* representation of the group, but presumably it will carry one, which may be reducible, but does not need to contain *every* representation.  For instance, the even harmonic oscillator states $\{\vert 2n\rangle\}$ transform by a *single* representation of $\mathfrak{sp}(2,\mathbb{R})$, the odd states by *one* other, but there are plenty of other representations that we don’t see.

Spin is treated no different than anything other group or algebra.  If there are no elementary particles with $s=7/2$, this is because of the physics of the model, not because of the group theory behind the model.  Conversely, simply knowing $s$ isn’t enough to say anything about the number of particles.

Consider for instance
\begin{align}
\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2-\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)\vert +\rangle_3\, ,\\
\vert \textstyle \frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{2}\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2-\vert -\rangle_1\vert +\rangle_2\right)\vert -\rangle_3\, .
\end{align}
These are clearly a 3-particle states, yet both of them span the Hilbert space of a 2-dimensional irrep of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.  The matrix representations of the spin operators would be exactly the $2\times 2$ Pauli matrices.

The job of the theorist is often to *explain* why this irrep does or does not appear: representation theory cannot tell you this no more than the theory of differential equations can tell you why you have this rather than that boundary condition to determine your solution.

Comment: Sorry I meant $s=1/2$. I've changed the question. So in reference to the above comment, what is preventing all the other $SU(2)$ irreps for a one-particle state?

Comment: Why do you think something prevents them? Spin-1 particles exist.

Comment: @fqq How do I form a spin $2$ one particle state using the Pauli equation though?

Comment: @DIRAC1930 I don't know what you mean by "form a state using an equation", but obviously if you start with an equation for spin-1/2 particles you get spin-1/2 particles.

Comment: @fqq So how would I go about forming a non-relativistic wave equation for spin $1$ particles?

Comment: @fqq So if I found for example a $U(1)$ symmetry, all the irreps are allowed and the state space will transform under a direct product of all the irreducible representations of $U(1)$?

Comment: What does the direct product of all the irreps of $U(1)$ have to do with this? Does it even exist?

Comment: @DIRAC1930  You can combine irreps to make other irreps, but that doesn’t link the irrep label to the number of particles.  You can have a single particle state with $j=2$ if you want, or $j=73/2$ if you care for this.  There is *nothing* to prevent single particle irreps to have $j=73/2$ or whatever.  You can if you want construct a $73/2$ particle by combining $73$ spin-1/2 states, but you can also get this by combining $j_1=35$ with $j_2=17/2$ or whatever, provided $\vert j_1-j_2\vert \le 73/2\le j_1+j_2$ and that one of $j_1$ or $j_2$ is integer while the other is half-integer.

Comment: so *nothing* prevents $j=2$ states from being single particle states.  It is or it isn’t; this just depends on the physics of the problem.  The group theory doesn’t care about the number of particles.

Comment: @fqq $u(1)$ is abelian; irreps are labelled by $m$ so the tensor product decomposes into a single irrep with $M=m_1+m_2$.

Comment: @fqq Sorry I meant direct sum because all representations can be constructed from the direct sum of irreps

Comment: @zerothehero So why don’t we get such particles in nature?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I know, which is why I think the direct product of all irreps is not well defined. Anyway, that's irrelevant.

Comment: @fqq that depends on the *physics*,  not representation theory.  The tensor product (or direct product) is certainly well defined *mathematically*.  A particular product may not have any physical relevance (because of - say - spin statistics or whatever other condition of the model) but that’s physics, not math.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero again it's completely irrelevant so let's not continue this discussion here, but I don't think the tensor product of an infinite number of irreps is well defined in general and in particular for *all* irreps of $U(1)$, as it would have charge $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}m$.